# В каком случае используется System.Int32 вместо int

Tags: c#

Куратор сегодня задал вопрос: «В каком случае используется `System.Int32` вместо `int`, `System.String` вместо `string`, и так далее при объявлении типа?»

Ведь это одно и тоже, так?  Но он сказал, что есть ситуации, когда нужно указывать `System.*`.

Comment: Можно использовать в любом, с точки зрения языка это одно и то же.

Comment: Можно предположить, что имеется в виду получение типа по его имени, через рефлексию -- там, вероятно (не проверял), допустимо только "строгое" имя типа.

Comment: `nameof(System.Int32)` компилируется, а `nameof(int)` - нет.

Comment: @nzeemin: Ага, вы правы: http://ideone.com/JflwaE

Comment: @VladD, какая-то странная проверка :-) `int` и т.д. это ж на время compile-time только, а рефлексия в run-time - естественно там ничего похожего быть не может

Comment: Может собрать все эти примеры: nameof, строковые литералы, - и сделать общий ответ?

Comment: @i-one, в `nameof` вообще довольно много ограничений на то, что можно подставить

Comment: @Grundy: Угу. Во время компиляции отличий (почти) нету, для языка это одно и то же. А вот в рантайма, при общении с CLR, видно, что `int` существует лишь во время компиляции.

Comment: @VladD, а какие отличия во время компиляции?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, то же `nameof`, например. А ещё в старых версиях языка `enum` можно было наследовать от `int`, но не `System.Int32`.

Comment: @VladD, ну nameof там вообще что-то они написали кучу ограничений, а enum да, но это тоже уже побеждено :)

Comment: Надеюсь, что и с `nameof` как-то разберутся.

Comment: @Grundy, я в том смысле, что, например, `typeof` и `sizeof` принимают оба варианта. Тут аналогично просится. Неконсистентность некоторая.

Comment: @i-one, а я про то, что в справке по `nameof` - прямо описаны варианты которые допустимы и какие нет. В то время как, например при определении enum такого не было

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` является ключевым словом, которое, в свою очередь, является псевдонимом `System.Int32`. Это высечено в спецификации, поэтому трактовке и изменениям не подлежит. Следовательно, таких ситуаций в языке C# нет.

Всё это относится и к другим «встроенным» типам(string, float, object и т.д).

---

Хотя это и не относится непосредственно к вопросу, тем не менее, `int` не получится использовать в выражении `nameof` — придётся использовать `System.Int32`. Хотя подобное использование, на мой взгляд, интересно лишь в познавательном ключе и никакого практического применения не имеет.